# 0% connecting to security.ubuntu.com(91.189.88.162) errro while upating the repositoy on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to update the repository  in Ubuntu 16.04 in Oracle VM Virtual  Box, I am getting the below message and it is not completing

0% connecting to security.ubuntu.com(91.189.88.162).

I tried disabling ipv6  but still I am getting the same error. Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue?   I want to install Hadoop on Ubuntu.  However I am stuck at first step while updating the repository.

Thanks,
Vijaya

Answer (score 0):

IP address `91.189.88.162` doesn't point to a IPv6 problem.

Maybe you can try to change the download server, for a temporary workaround. Go to System settings > Update Manager and, in the first section "Ubuntu Software", change the "Download from:" to another source.